# Is nested IF statements the best function to use

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, nested

I am trying to decide which function is better to use in Excel worksheet where I am asking Excel to give me one of three responses. My initial function looks like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G6:M6)"Error",IF(G6=0),O6=F6/E6),IF(G6)=F6/E6,O6=0)))
```

I am working from my data (Frequency, Minutes per task, Days per week, and Total minutes per week). So users may enter 1 for frequency, 30 for minutes, 5 for days of the week, and Excel provides me a total of minutes.

From there I have cells marked Sun-Sat which allows users to leave blank, enter a zero, or enter a number of minutes for each corresponding day. Let's say cells G6-M6. I also have cells O6 through U6 that need to perform a function based on what the user does in `G6-M6`.

If G6-M6 is left blank I need Excel to return "Error". If cells `G6-M6` contain a number of minutes I need Cells O6-U6 to remain blank. If cells `G6-M6` remain blank I need cells `O6-U6` to reflect minutes per week divided by days per week.

Comment: _"If cells G6-M6 remain blank I need cells O6-U6 to reflect minutes per week divided by days per week."_ **contradict with**  _"If G6-M6 is left blank I need Excel to return "Error"."_ ... or is it a typo?

Comment: is this  `=if(ISBLANK(G6:M6),ERROR.TYPE(7),if(G6=0,F6/E6,0))` the function you are looking for?